# How to override JSON.stringify method, NOT IN THE CUSTOM CALL, in the JSON class of the TypeScript project?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, object, stringify

I have React Native and TypeScript app. Every week get the error from Fabric: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures. There is no scenario of the error. And i have a lot of third part libraries that uses JSON.stringify. It means it is not possible put every where a custom method. Therefore i can not catch this error. There is a boot file in the root of my project where i can override all classes. I made a helper that catchs serialize cyclic structures:

```
const getCircularReplacer = () => {
  const seen = new WeakSet();

  return (key: any, value: any) => {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
      if (seen.has(value)) {
        return jsonStringify.circularReferenceReplacement;
      }
      seen.add(value);
    }

    return value;
  };
};

interface IJsonStringify {
  (value: any, replacer?: (this: any, key: string, value: any) => any, space?: string | number): string;
  circularReferenceReplacement?: any;
}

export const jsonStringify: IJsonStringify = (value: any, replacer?: (this: any, key: string, value: any) => any, space?: string | number): string => {
  return JSON.stringify(value, replacer || getCircularReplacer(), space);
};
```

When i try to override my JSON.stringify in my boot file like this:

```
JSON.stringify = (value: any) => {
  return jsonStringify(value);
};
```

I get this error: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Please can somebody write what I'm doing wrong or recommend how can i override my JSON class according my helper.

Answer (score 1):

Your method will not only delete cyclic references but also any seen objects, try using this:

```
function decycle(obj, stack = []) {
    if (!obj || typeof obj !== 'object')
        return obj;

    if (stack.includes(obj))
        return null;

    let s = stack.concat([obj]);

    return Array.isArray(obj)
        ? obj.map(x => decycle(x, s))
        : Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(obj)
                .map(([k, v]) => [k, decycle(v, s)]));
}
```

And you just call it like this `JSON.stringify(decycle(yourJson))`.

As for this:

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

You have a recursive function that calls itself with no exit condition.

Comment: But i can not override like this: JSON.stringify(decycle(yourJson), because i don't know yourJson argument, only if like this: JSON.stringify = function(value) {
  return JSON.stringify(decycle(value));
}, but i get the error again: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Answer (score 1):

Consider using json-stringify-safe

```
const {getSerialize} = require('json-stringify-safe');

const stringifyCore = JSON.stringify;
JSON.stringify = function (obj, replacer, spaces, cycleReplacer) {
    return stringifyCore(obj, getSerialize(replacer, cycleReplacer), spaces);
};
```

this should fix your Maximum call stask exceeded error.